# How to append XML content to an HTML element as if it were HTML and apply CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I have an XML file called 'layouts.xml' that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layouts>
   <layout id="layoutA">
     <div class="layout typeA">
       <div class="class1"></div>
       <div class="class2"></div>
     </div>
   </layout>
   <layout id="layoutB">
     <div class="layout typeB">
       <div class="class1"></div>
       <div class="class3"></div>
     </div>
   </layout>
</layouts>
```

Each 'layout' element in the XML contains a set of div elements that I want to insert into my webpage dynamically as HTML. I am attempting to do this like so:

```
$.fn.myFunc = function () {
   var url = "layouts.xml";
   var $element = $(this);  // element to append to

   $.get(url, function (responseXml) {
      var $layout = $(responseXml).find('#layoutA').children();
          $element.empty();
          $element.append($layout);
   });
}

$('div#myDiv').myFunc();
```

This inserts the markup into my webpage, but the CSS styles I have created for these dynamically inserted div elements are not being applied. The styles are applied to HTML elements that already exist, but not to any dynamically added content. I have validated the CSS, XML and resulting HTML using the online w3c services.

I would really appreciate some help getting these CSS styles to apply! Thank you.

Comment: It should work check this http://jsfiddle.net/jzbPz/ can you show your css?

Comment: I have confirmed that it works when I append the XML as text, but I have only been able to get the text via the XMLSerializer class. The 'responseXml' object is a #document, and something about the way I am getting $layout prevents me from accessing the underlying XML with $.text() and/or $.html().

Answer (score 1):

After switching to the $.ajax() method and specifying a dataType of 'text', I was able to append the XML as shown below:

```
var $element = $('div#myDiv');

$.ajax({
    url: 'layouts.xml',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        var $layout = $(data).find('.layout typeA');
        $element.empty();
        $element.append($layout.html());
    }
});
```

As Tap pointed out, I needed to append the XML as text. However, I could not get the XML as text from the XML document object via the $.text() or $.html() methods, so I had to change the AJAX request so it would give me the XML as text (instead of as an XML document object).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending an xml element into your html DOM, append the text value of it.

```
$element.append($layout.html());
```

Or for multiple children,

```
$layout.each(function(){
    $element.append($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: $layout.text() is returning a long string of nothing but whitespace and CR+LF... any idea why?

Comment: I have gotten it to work when I use XMLSerializer, but I fear this is not the best solution because it is browser-specific.

Comment: What is the context of 'this' in 'var $element = $(this)'?  It's working for me - with styles on class1 and class2.

Comment: The enclosing function is declared as $.fn.myFunc(), so 'this' is in the scope of that method. The invocation looks like this: $('div#myDiv').myFunc() -> where #myDiv is the div to append the HTML into.